# If using Spring Boot, how can I detect what class is not setup correctly for autowired?

Tags: java, spring, exception, spring-boot

In our Spring Boot application yesterday we ran into an issue with `javax.management.InstanceNotFoundException` was being thrown. We saw the logs coming from the `run.rmi.runtime.Log$Logger`. This is caused when a class is being `@Autowired` but the configuration for the bean has not been done such as by using the `@Component` on the class that will be autowired. Also when this happens the application just terminates with an exit code of 1 and you really don't know why or what class caused the problem.

Question is how can I programmatically detect that this is happening so that the logs can accurately logs where the problem is and shutdown the application gracefully.

The current way is just a pain and we were fortunate to be able to see what is going on before the application development got too far along where a bad setup could possibly end up with days lost trying to figure out what broke the system.

Comment: `InstanceNotFoundException` isn't really related to what you describe. `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException` would be the exception thrown when you attempt to autowire a non-component class.

Comment: I am new to Spring and what I'm seeing is javax.management.InstanceNotFoundException when Autowire is placed onto a reference to a Class which does not have the Component on the Class. When I remove the Autowire altogether the error/issue does not occur.

Comment: Well `javax.management` has nothing to do with Spring, so you must have an interesting setup. Apparently some sort of RMI logging mechanism. You might want to figure how you see the **real** exceptions, because now you're losing information. Once you have that handled, you'll realize it's not as big an issue as you think. When you get a `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException` telling you that "fooBean" hasn't been defined, it's a rather simple fix instead of "days lost".

Comment: That is kind of what I'm saying. We have this obscure exception but it does not tell us what really caused it. All I know is that it can be reproduced by not properly marking a class with the annotation @ Configuration

Comment: Yeah you should edit the question to explain your setup and how you get that exception. In a normal setup you'd get a different exception in the logs. What kind of logging are you using?

Comment: Logging is done via slf4j. As for the whole project that is setup, it was done by a developer who just left 2 weeks ago. I've not done anything with Spring before but was told to try and figure out how we can determine and log what class causes such an exception when the Class does not have the annotation marking it as a Component. Personally I would not think it to be possible but nonetheless I'm looking to see if I am wrong. As for rewording how the things are setup I can't even begin to answer that.

Comment: I on the other hand am quite familiar with Spring and I understand what you're describing. The only thing that doesn't make sense are the parts about `javax.management` and `run.rmi.runtime`. Do all exceptions end up being logged like that, or is it just this case? They shouldn't be appearing in your logs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162622/discussion-between-elijah-and-kayaman).